# Execute multiple regex one after another or combine multiple regex into one

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am using notepad++, I have wrote few regex which have eased my work in formatting file. However to format the file in desired format I have to execute multiple regex, I wanted to know is there some possible way where I will store my list of regular expression and it will execute one after another.

Here is the file tree.txt which needs to be formatted.

```
overview/Main_Overview/Gas Management/BOG MV/BOG MV Process Alarms:Tag=BOG Heaters Process Alarms:Device=:Color=-3355444
overview/Main_Overview/Gas Management/BOG MV/BOG MV Process Trip:Tag=BOG Heaters Process Alarms-1:Device=:Color=-3355444
overview/Main_Overview/Gas Management/BOG MV/BOG MV External Trip:Tag=BOG Heaters Process Alarms-1-1:Device=:Color=-3355444
```

The regex will truncate above text and arrange in this sed format.

```
s/BOG Heaters Process Alarms:/BOG MV Process Alarms:/g
s/BOG Heaters Process Alarms-1:/BOG MV Process Trip:/g
s/BOG Heaters Process Alarms-1-1:/BOG MV External Trip:/g
```

To achieve the above result I will do some set of regex operation one after another.

```
Find- .*/
Replace- 

Find- Device=:.*
Replace- 

Find- :Tag=
Replace- /

Find- (^.*/)([^/]+):
Replace- /\2/ \1

Find- ^
Replace- s

Find- $
Replace- g
```

After above regex I get the desired format however I need to know if this can be combined so that I don't need to do manually after each expression gets completed or reduce to one expression.
Thanks

Comment: [Macros - Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Macros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the elements you need, especially grouping. You need to find:

```
^.*/(.*:)Tag=(.*:)Device=.*$
```

Then replace with:

```
s/\2/\1/g
```

Note that this gives the `sed` parameters you quote as what you want to produce, whereas your sequence would omit the colon in the `sed` find string and add a leading blank in the `sed` replacement string, giving:-

```
s/BOG Heaters Process Alarms/ BOG MV Process Alarms:/g
s/BOG Heaters Process Alarms-1/ BOG MV Process Trip:/g
s/BOG Heaters Process Alarms-1-1/ BOG MV External Trip:/g
```

To reproduce your sequence you would need to search for:

```
^.*/(.*):Tag=(.*:)Device=.*$
```

Then replace with:

```
s/\2/ \1/g
```

However, the `sed` substitutions won't work unless made in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I didn't knew we could group this way.